# Segmented Control not Working

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I've been working through a tutorial on raywenderlich.com called Objectively Speaking: [A Crash Course in Objective-C](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12444/objectively-speaking-a-crash-course-in-objective-c). In the tutorial they use a segmented control, which to my understanding I've connected correctly in IB. I've tried posting my problem but after 5 days I still haven't had any help.

I suspect the problem is something like a connection issue. Could someone please look at my project and let me know where I've gone wrong. The zip files can be found here: [Options, Options, Options](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums//viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3663&start=20#p29950).

Comment: You should describe your problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two segmented controls in your XIB, one on top of the other.

The problem is that the bottom segmented control is hooked up via the IBOutlet, but you're actually selecting the segmented index of the top one.

To fix it, delete the bottom segmented control (the one with out constraints) and hook up the IBOutlet to the single remaining segmented control.

Comment: Thanks! This community rocks! I deleted one of the controls and hooked up the other. Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in `appDelegate.m` class and it will work. Its happening because you are not below than iOS 5.

```
@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write your listener yourself.

```
[urSegmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentControlValueChangedListener:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to do it in interface builder:

First of all - open ViewController.m class file and create function like this - it will be called, when You change segment:

[image]

Then open ViewController.xib and with second mouse button tap-and-hold on Segmented Control instance - and pull to File Responder. Release. It will show up a view like this:

[image]

Select newly created function name. That's it - now, when value segment value will be changed, **quote_opt_touch** function will be called, and in debugger You will see "abc".

Also - You had Two segmented controls. Remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your xib file.  You have two instances of the `segmentedcontrol` declared.  You need to remove the bottom one and re-connect the top one to the outlet.